# Using wm_concat to concatenate rows, but in an order determined by another column

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, group-concatenation

Let's say I have 3 columns: `p_id`, `description`, `order_by`.  I am trying to do the following:

I would like to concatenate the description for all like `p_id` values.  So we are talking a `group by p_id` sort of thing.  But then, I want the description to be concatenated in the order of the `order_by` column (which is an integer).  So my ideal query (not-working) would look like

```
select p_id, wm_concat(description)
from my_table
where p_id = 12345
group by p_id
order by order_by asc
```

How do I concatenate rows in this fashion?

Comment: What version of Oracle? Oracle 11g has `listagg` which can use `order by`.

Comment: @bluefeet - Yes I do, I guess I have never used it before.  Now, I have figured out how to manipulate the above to use listagg instead of wm_concat.  The new problem I get is a `ORA-01489 result of string concatenation is too long`.  Gotta look into this before I can share my final query.

Comment: Oh my, 4000 chars is all I get?  Well my concatenation is definitely longer than that.

Comment: String aggregates can only be 4000 bytes, see this answer on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795220/listagg-function-result-of-string-concatenation-is-too-long/13795436#13795436) about other options.

Comment: @bluefeet Yeah thanks a bunch.  I think that is the sort of approach we are going to have to go with.  I am going to write an answer and you can write an answer if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the query (which would work if under 4000 bytes) is

```
select p_id, listagg(description, '\n') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY order_by)
from my_table
where p_id = 12345
group by p_id
```